# Packaging static iOS libraries together on command line

Tags: ios, static-linking, lipo, libtool-xcode

I have a static iOS library built for armv7 and arm64, let's call it foo.a. It has dependencies on abc.a and def.a, which I have in armv7 and arm64 versions. I would like to package these together into one static library, so you can just use foo.a without having to include abc.a and def.a in your project.

In short, I would like to do something akin to

```
link arm64/abc.a arm64/def.a armv7/abc.a armv7/def.a foo.a -out foo.a
```

But I can't figure it which tool I'm supposed to use for this, or if I'm using them wrong. I've tried libtool, as such:

```
libtool -static arm64/abc.a arm64/def.a armv7/abc.a armv7/def.a foo.a -o foo.a
```

But I get the error message

```
Unrecognized option: '-static'
```

I've tried lipo

```
lipo -create -output foo.a arm64/abc.a arm64/def.a armv7/abc.a armv7/def.a foo.a
```

But I get the error message

```
fatal error: lipo: foo.a and armv7/abc.a have the same architecture (armv7) and can't be in the same fat output file
```

I must be misunderstanding something fundamental about this process, but I'm having a hard time finding out what

Comment: Do you own the source code of the static lib? If yes there are many tutorial that create far library with run script

Comment: @Tj3n I do, but we compile that from the command line too, and all the tutorials I can find talk about Xcode menu configurations. If you know of any tutorials for this through the cl, I'd love to read it

Comment: Not sure about cl, I only know that build for device then you are already have arm64, armv7, armv7s, maybe you already did so? You can use lipo to check all the architectures your lib containing

Comment: Yes, the foo.a library is built for armv7 and arm64 with the Xcode flag ARCHS="armv7 arm64", but abc.a and def.a are not multi-architecture, they have two libs each for armv7 and arm64 respectively